# Как устроенны уведомления windows?

Tags: windows

Может кто-то объяснить, как устроены уведомления в новых Windows.

Как конкретно функционирует notification API, с помощью каких именно протоколов, методов. Я само API на сайте вижу, для использования в с#, но не нахожу информации как устроено оно под капотом.

Хочется понять как устроено. Платформа - настольный пк.

Comment: Платформу укажите пожалуйста.

Comment: для настольного ПК

Comment: Я может чего-то не понимаю, но разве это не чисто браузерная примочка? Каким боком тут Windows?

Comment: причем тут браузер? уведомления в центре уведомлений windows - он так и называется. появился вроде с 8 версии

Comment: Могу ошибиться, но вряд ли такая информация является открытой где-либо вне стен Microsoft.